# Issue in jquery ajax on download file link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my page i have download links to files like Documents,Audio and Video and on click of that download link i want to update hits counter in database for that i use the strategy of jquery ajax request that will update hits counter but the issue is when i click on hyperlink it call the jquery function but doesnt call my controller action and download popups appear. What may be the issue for reference im writing the code

```
<a att="1" href="../Abc.doc">Download</a>
<a att="2" href="../Abcs.wmv">Download</a>
```

and in jquery

```
  $('a').click(function () {
                    var myurl = '<%= Url.Action("UpdateHits", "Media") %>';
                    var id = $(this).attr('att').toString();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: myurl,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { Id: id },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you cancel the default action by returning `false` so that the browser doesn't follow the link.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    var myurl = '<%= Url.Action("UpdateHits", "Media") %>';
    var id = $(this).attr('att').toString();
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { Id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also instead of going through all this pain in javascript I would recommend you generating proper anchor links:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Abc.doc", "UpdateHits", "Media", new { id = 1 }, null) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Abcs.wmv", "UpdateHits", "Media", new { id = 2 }, null) %>
```

And simply ajaxify them:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $.post(this.href, function(data) {
            alert('success');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ajax call is working, but now the download popup is not coming

Comment: Your `UpdateHits` action needs to `return File(byteArray, "text/plain")` and probably set the `Content-Disposition` header as well to `attachment; filename=test.txt` (adjust content-type as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
     $('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
                        var myurl = '<%= Url.Action("UpdateHits", "Media") %>';
                        var id = $(this).attr('att').toString();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: myurl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { Id: id },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
return true;
                    });
```

Prevent default stops the link from being followed until the js is through doing what it needs to, throw in the return truie to let it continue with the link follow.

Comment: `return true` will do nothing here, because (1) ajax is asynchronous -- return true will be done before the success callback and (2) calling `e.preventDefault()` is canonical and is not overridden by the return value of the handler function.  If you want to continue following the link once the AJAX is complete, you'll need to use `window.location` inside the success callback.